# How to remove current directory from python import path

Tags: python, linux, mercurial

I want to work with the mercurial repository of `hg` itself. That is, I cloned Mercurial from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg and want to run some `hg` commands inside the cloned repository. The problem is that when running `hg` inside this clone `hg` executable tries to load its python modules from this directory and not from `/usr/lib/pythonVERSION` etc. As I understand it this happens because Python import path `sys.path` contains an empty string as first entry which probably means "current directory". `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is not set.

The questtion is how can I prevent my installed `hg` from importing "wrong" modules.

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0,"/usr/lib/pythonVERSION")`?

Comment: Where should I put it? I don't want to modify the system `hg` script.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would deal with the topic is by creating a `/usr/local/bin/hg` sh script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/pythonVERSION/site-packages /usr/bin/hg
```

(Ubuntu-based distributives use `dist-packages` instead of `site-packages`)

`PYTHONPATH` is a special environment variable respected by Python interpreter to get extra module import paths.

Alternatively, you can export `PYTHONPATH` into your shell, but it will affect your whole experience.

Comment: Hm, oddly enough that does not work for me. It still seems to prefer the local version of the package :/

Answer (score -1):

@ragol, i think Padraic has the correct solution. Within the python script that you are trying to run hg commands, you need to include the following command: `sys.path.insert(0,"/usr/lib/pythonVERSION")`

Place the command at the very beginning of your python script. The command tells python to look in the `/usr/lib/pythonVERSION` directory first when importing modules.

If that doesn't work, you may need to be more specific with the path. For example, if the module you are trying to import is located in the `/usr/lib/pythonVERSION/site-packages/hg` directory, you could use the following command: `sys.path.insert(0,"/usr/lib/pythonVERSION/site-packages/hg")`

Comment: The script I try to run is `/usr/bin/hg` which is mercurial itself. May be I don't understand you correctly, but it seems that you suggest to modify it. That is of course the simplest solution, but it would mean that I would modify a file installed by package manager. I don't like this idea. I'd rather write an external script that calls `/usr/bin/hg` in such a way that it doesn't load modules from current directory.

Comment: what is the name of the script you are running? does it have the .py extension? im assuming that you have either created or edited some python script and are trying to import a module called mercurial. what i am suggesting is to include the sys.path.insert command before the line where you try to import the mercurial module