# Force python not to add the directory of a script to the import locations

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, pythonpath

When I run a script `pyhton path/to/app.py` then the directory `path/to` is put upfront on the list of locations where python will look for modules to import.

Is there a way to force python not to do that? That is running a script without having its directory being put on the import path (or have it added as lowest priority instead of highest one)?

---

The reason is that within this directory I have another module called `threading` and my script imports `logging` which itself issues an `import threading` which then resolves to my custom `threading` module instead of the built-in one:

```
$ tree
.
└── app
    ├── main.py
    └── threading.py

$ cat app/main.py
import logging
```

`python app/main.py` results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    _lock = threading.RLock()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RLock'
```

Comment: It looks like this is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533631/how-to-remove-current-directory-from-python-import-path   ... It seems like you just need to insert the python module import path at the beginning of the path variable

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two options here:

1. Edit `sys.path` to give python packages first preference. Very easy    to do. It's just a `list` of strings. Do some list manipulation to    add first items at the end.
2. Move threading.py from root, into another package. Like `processing.threading`.

If I was in your place, I'd choose the second option as it helps keep the code clean in long run.